# What causes 'Task Scheduler' to hang my application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application that connects to a remote database. It runs fine if I run the .exe file, 
However If I run the .exe as a task in 'Task Scheduler', my program hangs when it tries to connect to the database.
This is the line that hangs.
[image]

this is a normal DbConnection implementation. 
IDbConnection.Open().

What could cause this?

Comment: you need to give us some more information, a snippet with the code illustrating where the program hangs would be helpful

Comment: Please refer to my update.

Comment: There is no error message?

Comment: Nope, It just waits to connect to the database, but no error message. It doesn't terminate, just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below links:

[How to find out the reason why a scheduled task hang?](https://superuser.com/questions/801436/how-to-find-out-the-reason-why-a-scheduled-task-hang)

[Scheduled Tasks appear hung in the “Running” state on Windows Server 2003 based systems](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rspitz/archive/2010/11/07/scheduled-tasks-appear-hung-in-the-running-state-on-windows-server-2003-based-systems.aspx)

It will help you to identify what causes 'Task schedule' to hang your application and also to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was Administrator privilege.
I had to run the task with the highest privileges.